# Positioning Column Chart to specific Cells in an existing worksheet VB

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble positioning a column chart in a specific range of cells on an existing worksheet. Does someone having any advice? Also How do I display data lables to the top of the bars? Also, How do I resize a legend for a piechart? Thank you in advance!

```
            Dim data As Worksheet
            Dim colChart As Chart

     Set data = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'have charts in data ws
    Set colChart = data.Shapes.AddChart.Chart ' set col chart
    Set pieChart = data.Shapes.AddChart.Chart 'set pie chart

     With colChart
  .HasLegend = False 'no legend
  .ChartType = xlColumnClustered 'clustered column
  .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range("E2:E7"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
  .HasTitle = True
  .ChartTitle.Text = "Statictics on 50,000 Dice" 'title
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True ' axis title
  .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dice Face"
  .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True 'axis title
  .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Counts"

     End With
```

Comment: You can use colChart.Top and colChart.Left to position the chart relative to a cell using the cell's Top and Left properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a macro of you manually doing what you want. Excel will record some code you don't want, just delete it. The recorded macro should answer your questions.